# Can't Create folder using QDir in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm trying to create a folder in a certain path the user choose but for some reason the folder couldn't be created I don't know why... my code is the following:

```
QString ExpoPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Export File to:", QDir::currentPath());

QString datapath = ExpoPath + "/Data";

QDir dir(datapath);
if(!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdir("Data");
    if(QFile::exists(datapath)){
        qDebug() << "Directory Created" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should created `QDir` out of an existing path `ExpoPath` and than create a sub directory `Data`. I.e. `QDir dir(ExpoPath); dir.mkdir("Data");`.

Comment: I tried this code in a new blank project and it worked fine... I don't know why it doesn't work in my other project, that's weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
QDir().mkpath(datapath);
```

From the [document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath), this will create all parent directories necessary to create the directory.

By using this way we can avoid that one of the parent directories does not actually exist in some cases.

Comment: Please always try to explain your solution and if possible provide a reference to the official docs.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.